# Python unittest module, general assertion logger

Tags: python, python-unittest

I am writing selenium tests for my Windows Phone 8 application by using [`https://github.com/2gis/winphonedriver`](https://github.com/2gis/winphonedriver) framework

I am using `unittest` module, as a 'base' test framework

And I wanna make a screenshot of device screen when at least one assertion failed.

Question:

Does `unittest` module have some specific function/method which called in case when assertion failed?

Comment: As far as I know, it doesn't have anything that is called after the test has failed to indicate success or failure that you can hook into naively.  You could build your own test runner -- I've never done it, but the docs don't make it seem *too* hard.  Alternatively, you could override `self.fail` as that is the method that is supposed to raise AssertionError when an assertion fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now I have found only one solution http://www.piware.de/2012/10/python-unittest-show-log-on-test-failure/

I have just post a code from link above

```
class MyTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def run(self, result=None):
        '''Show log output on failed tests'''

        if result:
            orig_err_fail = result.errors + result.failures

        super().run(result)

        if result and result.errors + result.failures > orig_err_fail:
            print ("assertion failed")
```